# How To Use Python for a Web App?

Tags: python, web2py, pyramid

I am creating a school management system that handles file uploads and downloads from teachers and students. Furthermore, there will be a large amount of database writes and reads (e.g. which classes a student is taking, what the student's grades are etc.)

I want dynamic web pages updated with python using an AJAX model on the front end.

On the back end I want to use python for file handling, database reads to show user their content, database writes when a user updates his/her content on the web app and **memcache**.

The stack I am using is...

CentOS + Hadoop + Hypertable + Python

I am currently going through the [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.1/index.html) docs and after going past a few chapters, I don't see how pyramid helps me accomplish what I can do in PHP, and if it does do this, why so complicated?

Is pyramid the right tool, or should I be using [web2py](http://web2py.com/)?

If pyramid is the best tool, where can I see some sample code of a complex application built in pyramid. I tend to understand best when reading other's code.

*Django cannot be used due to inflexibility*

Comment: Look into [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python and web development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641616/python-and-web-development)

Comment: "I have already looked into Django. The reason I chose not to use Django is due to scalability issues and inflexibility."  Can you substantiate those claims?  They sound like they could be assumptions or misinformation.

Comment: @S.Lott It could possibly be misinformation, but from what I see Django is best used with their own ORM. I have heard things breaking down when someone uses Django with another database (e.g. MySQL)

Comment: @Jimmy Huch: Django's ORM sits on top of other databases, including MySQL.  If you're referring to using manual queries instead of the ORM, then you'll obviously have stuff "breaking down".  On thing Django does is run each view in a database transaction (by default).  With manual queries, you'll obviously be losing such nice features.

Comment: @André Caron I understand the ORM sits on top of other databases, but not my database of my choice --> Hypertable. Therefore a flexibility problem as I mentioned before.

Comment: @Jimmy Huch: sorry, wasn't clear from your comment.

Comment: @André Caron Yes I tend to talk in general terms vs specific terms :)

Comment: @Jimmy Huch: "I tend to talk in general terms".  Can you fix the question, then to be very, very specific?  It would help us to understand what you're talking about if you could stick to **details**.

Comment: @Jimmy Huch: Now, could you also do us another favor by editing the question into one coherent question.  The "Edit/Update" history isn't helpful.  Indeed, it makes it hard to integrate all the information into one question.  Also, can you take out the "This would be very simple if I were using PHP, but it is different for Python.
", since that's subjective and argumentative.

Comment: You might swing by the #pyramid IRC channel on freenode.net.  Not sure what you're confused about but we can probably clear it up quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't see how pyramid helps me accomplish what I can do in PHP, and if it does do this, why so complicated?

1. A web framework like Pyramid is not a web framework like PHP.  They're different.
2. Complexity is a matter of "experience".  If you're experienced with PHP, Python seems complex.  If your experienced with RoR, PHP seems complex.  Everything that's new seems complex.
3. Python has a dozen or so web frameworks of varying capabilities.  None of them will look like PHP.  Zero.  They'll all be different (and appear complex).
4. Consequently, if you don't like one.  Move on.  There are a lot of choices.  Keep trying different ones.
5. Ask **specific** questions.  "I don't see how pyramid helps me accomplish what I can do in PHP" is too vague to discuss further.  If there's a specific thing you want to know about, search for that **specific** question (it's probably already been asked).   If you don't find anything, ask the **specific** question.  Code samples help.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend you use Django.

https://www.djangoproject.com/

Django is a great way to do a project like this, and the documentation is outstanding.  There is a free book, called The Django Book, which you can read online.

http://www.djangobook.com/

This book is a few years out of date.  I haven't been keeping up with Django but I am pretty sure that the book will still be useful.  Use the book to learn the concepts, and use the actual Django documentation to look up specifics.

Comment: Indeed, the book is still highly recommended.  Most of what changed in Django since then is related to more advanced topics.  All the code examples should run just fine on newer versions of Django.

Comment: The OP also mistakes being tied to an ORM framework as being tied to a specific database.   You can use other ORM frameworks in Django, you just don't get as far with CRUD/admin type stuff.  And I've known folks using MySQL in Django with Django ORM along-side non-Django apps using SQLAlchemy.  It's all doable.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some great luck with Django, its pretty well documented and has examples that do exactly what you seem to do